# QTabWidget within a QTabWidget

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside2

I am having to parent a QTabWidget (tab_widget2) under another QTabWidget (tab_widget1). When I try to resize the main window, the tabwidgets don't resize, so I added the two tabwidgets into separate hboxlayouts. This works and resizing the window resizes the tabwidgets as well. However, now I cannot directly access tabwidget2's tabs and printing children() on tabwidget1 prints the hboxlayout and tabwidget2, which makes sense. But is there a way to query the current tab "in view"? hasFocus() doesn't work as I want to know what's in view even if it doesn't have focus.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(496, 482)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.tabWidget_2 = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.tab)
        self.tabWidget_2.setObjectName("tabWidget_2")
        self.tab_3 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget_2.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget_2)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.tab_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.tabWidget_3 = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.tab_2)
        self.tabWidget_3.setObjectName("tabWidget_3")
        self.tab_5 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget_3.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_6 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName("tab_6")
        self.tabWidget_3.addTab(self.tab_6, "")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget_3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.tabWidget_3.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.tab_3), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget_2.setTabText(self.tabWidget_2.indexOf(self.tab_4), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget_3.setTabText(self.tabWidget_3.indexOf(self.tab_5), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget_3.setTabText(self.tabWidget_3.indexOf(self.tab_6), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Form", "Tab 2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Edit: Added example. So, in that example with the focus in the lineEdit widget, how do I query for what tab in tabWidget_1 and what tab in tabWidget_2 is in view?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Added the example now. Hope that helps! If not, I can elaborate a bit more.